# Benefits of jQuery delegated-events approach for Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a Grid/Table with huge amounts of data like 1000s of rows and event handlers for each of the rows...

Now there are 2 ways of implementing the same;

1.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {}
```

and 
2.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {}
```

Could you please explain the basic difference between the 2 approach and how it can help in rendering/performance....

Answer (score 0):

Read  [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As new elements added by javascript are not part of DOM at DOM ready or page load so you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

This is Event Delegation

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on( "click", "tr", function() {
```

explanation of above code

We are attaching the event handler to the element with id `dataTable` containing  `tbody` tag so that if more `tr` is added `dynamically` than `click` event will work on the new added `tr`.

But if use below code than new added `tr` will not have `click event handler` attached to them.

---

Below code will work if the elements are  present in DOM at the DOM ready or Page Load.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {}
```

is equal to

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).click(function() {});
```

Comment: Thx a lot...Could you elaborate more on the rendering/performance benefit comparision between them...

Answer (score 0):

Delegation (method 2) must be used when the elements that match the selector change dynamically. You should only use this when necessary for that purpose. It establishes a handler on the element in the selector that `.on` is applied to, and then has to test whether the target element matches the selector in the argument list; this depends on the event bubbling from the inner element to the element you bind to. This is less efficient than binding directly to the target element, because the browser implements that entirely by itself.

The first form should be used when the elements are static. The selector matches all of them when the DOM is ready, and binds handlers to each of them.